# React+Redux value undefined mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

so i've this

index.js

```
import {getShowsHome} from './reducers/reducers';

const store = createStore(getShowsHome);
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}> <App /> </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
  tvSeries: state.getShowsHome.tvSeries,
  isPedding: state.getShowsHome.isPedding,
  movies: state.getShowsHome.movies,
  horror: state.getShowsHome.horror,
  scifiFantasySeries: state.getShowsHome.scifiFantasySeries
 }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
 getShows: () => dispatch(getShows())
 }
}
```

Reducer

```
const initialState = {
isPedding: true,
tvSeries: [],
movies: [],
horror: [],
scifiFantasySeries: []
}
export const getShowsHome = (state=initialState, action={}) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case GET_SHOWS_HOME_PEDDING:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {isPedding: true});
    case GET_SHOWS_HOME_SUCCESS:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
                                tvSeries: action.payload.popularSeries,
                                movies: action.payload.popularMovies,
                                horror: action.payload.horrorMovies,
                                scifiFantasySeries: action.payload.scifiFantasySeries,
                                isPedding: false,
                            });
    case GET_SHOWS_HOME_FAILED:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {error: action.payload});
    default: 
    return state;
}
}
```

So the problem is thet i get an error, i get tvSeries (only because it's the first) it undefined, it's like the store non pass the reducers at the App, why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your store will have the state directly, not under the 'getShowsHome' key, it's just the function name. so try

```
 tvSeries: state.tvSeries
```

in case you have multiple reducers, combineReducers (import from redux)

```
const store = createStore(combineReducers({ getShowsHome: getShowsHome, ....other here }))
```